# Find index of longest sub-list in 2D list

Tags: python, arrays

I originally had two arrays, one contained numbers, the other associated values:

```
scores =  [2,            4,     12 ... etc ]
players = ["Peter", "Brian", "Meg" ... etc]
top_score_index = scores.index(max(scores))
top_player = players[top_score_index]
```

This already stinks, because the `scores.index(max(scores))` obviously iterates over that list twice (in the worst case scenario).

Situation changed, the `scores` array now contains lists:

```
scores = [[something, something, something], [something, something]]
```

The score which I care about is however simply `len( scores[some_offset] )`, that is the length of nested list.

How can I easily find the index of longest of those nested lists? Eg. for:

```
[[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

I would expect return value of `2`. Please that **efficiency is a concern** for me right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scores = [[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
print(max((len(l), i) for i, l in enumerate(scores))[1])
```

Prints `2`.

You can't avoid calling `len` on each sublist, so I don't think you can do better as far as efficiency.

Comment: If I understand correctly, with `scores = [[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]` this will ouput `3`, that is, _last_ occurrence of maximum. To get the _first_ you can use something like `print(-max((len(l), -i) for i, l in enumerate(scores))[1])`

Comment: Yes, that would work to get the index of the first sublist with the maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

Use `enumerate()` to get the `(idx, value)` tuple while iterating over the score.

```
idx, max_val = 0, len(scores[0])
for idx, sublst in enumerate(scores):
    if len(sublst) > max_val:
        idx, max_val = idx, len(sublst)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about following pattern?

```
scores = [[0,0,0],[0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0]]
result = max(enumerate(scores), key=(lambda x: len(x[1])))
print(result[0])
print(result[1])
>>> 2
>>> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```